# else sem o if explicação

Tags: python, for, else

Até onde eu sei, o `else` deve ficar abaixo do `if`, correspondendo-o, mas no código abaixo, o else não está junto do `if` , pois está fora da estrutura de repetição, pra ser mais exato, o `else` não está nem identado, logo o mesmo era pra ser sempre executado e isto não acontece. E ainda assim o código funciona perfeitamente!

```
 L=[7,9,10,12]
 p=int(input("Digite um número a pesquisar:"))
 for e in L:
     if e == p:
        print("Elemento encontrado!")
        break 
 else: 
     print("Elemento não encontrado.")
```

Comment: No Python o comando `for` pode ter uma cláusula `else`. Consulte a documentação.

Comment: Ler a documentação ajuda bastante. Esse else é do `for .. else` e não do `if .. else`.

Comment: vlw galera, ajudou muito já tava ficando doido kkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse else é parte do for e não de uma IF, isso é normal em Python, é caracteristica da linguagem, conforme documentação:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

O `else` no seu caso é disparado quando **nenhum** `break` é executado, se um `break` for executado então `else` será disparado.

Vale lembrar que em While também temos isto, exemplo:

```
i = 1
j = 10 # Mude para 11 para que o else não dispare
busca = 11

while i <= j:
    if i == busca:
        print('Valor 11 encontrado')
        break

    i = i+1

else:
    print("Não foi encontrado o 11")
```

Comment: obrigado irmão, ajudou bastante!

Comment: "Se um `break` for executado então `else` **não** será disparado", certo?

Comment: @RafaelTavares certo, como eu disse: O else no seu caso é disparado quando nenhum break é executado, se um break for executado então else será disparado.

Answer (score 1):

Não é verdade que o `else` só deva vir junto de um `if`, ele pode vir para a situação quando um laço não conseguiu ser iterado até o fim do que se espera. Ele foi criado justamente para a situação mostrada nesse exemplo.

Ele funciona igual ao que usaria no `if`. Se o `break` for acionado então o `else` não será executado. Serve para o `while` também.

Quando existe esta cláusula o `break` muda a semântica e funciona como se fosse um `goto else` (o normal seria um `goto end`).

É esquisito? É, o mais correto aí seria uma cláusula chamada `then` e não `else`, já que ele executa quando o laço vai até o fim e sai de forma natural, mas a linguagem escolheu usar a mesma palavra chave do `if` e mudar a semântica.

Então podemos concluir que a indentação está correta, ele usa a mesma indentação do `for`. Ele não está fora da estrutura de repetição, ele está junto, uma segunda parte dele. E obviamente é usando opcionalmente quando faz sentido.

[Documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).